# Is the prime number 532660159 somehow "connected" to the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2017

If you do a `std::vector<double> v = std::vector<double>();` your vector is going to have a capacity equal to zero, fine.

Now I have an API having a function having a `std::vector<double>` reference parameter to which I pass a vector definied as above. And at debug, I see a capacity equal to ... `532660159`.

At the beginning I thought it was an `INT_MAX` of some sort, until I check that it is a prime number (between 2^28 and 2^29, and it's not even the biggest prime number smaller than 2^29.)

Just to be really sure (I am already sure of it in fact, but before harassing the API guys) : is this number connected somehow to the STL ?

*Some precisions.* The real setting is that I am in Python, using an API binding c++ code, in fact binding `std::vector<double>` and a c++ function `F` having as parameter a reference to such a vector. I see a normal capacity (zero) after initializing the vector binder in the python code, and I see the capacity being this prime number immediately after entering the c++ function binding `F`.

*Remark.* Following a comment of [hnefatl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193020/hnefatl) I did a little track down and :
`d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\xhash` has `#define _HASH_SEED    (size_t)0xdeadbeef` and `size_t hash_value(const _Kty& _Keyval)` uses it, and it appears in a comment in ... `c:\PYTHON\PYTHON_OFFICIAL\python-3.6.3\include\abstract.h` regarding the `long PyObject_Hash(PyObject *o)` which is implemented elsewhere, and used indeed I guess ... and I indeed rely on `python-3.6.3` ...

Of course, I would like to give a minimal reproducing example, but it's not easy --> I will give it this week-end.

Comment: It has the relatively pleasing hex code `1FBFBFBF`, which suggests it could be some [magic number like `DEADBEEF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values).

Comment: You sure you're not accessing an uninitialized variable?  I don't think that's standard behavior..

Comment: How, when and where do you see this number? Could it be an uninitialized `std::vector<double>` object? Do you see it before you actually enter the function so the vector haven't been properly passed yet? It it possible to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? With a comment telling exactly on which line you check the vector?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added some precisions to my question.

Comment: At most, it is connected to some implementation, VS in this case. Doing a search through libstdc++-5.4 (Ubuntu 16.04), there's no such number.

Comment: @hnefatl This is excellent ! I am on windows 8 or 10 though.

Comment: `d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\xhash` has ` #define _HASH_SEED (size_t)0xdeadbeef` and `size_t hash_value(const _Kty& _Keyval)` uses it, and it used in ... `c:\PYTHON\PYTHON_OFFICIAL\python-3.6.3\include\abstract.h` and I indeed rely on `python-3.6.3` ... Christ.

Comment: Is this the same problem? https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1230

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes, and actually I succeeded in tracking down the origin of the phenomenon, and I will now describe it here and there.